# How can I add a border to an image in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

The border needs to be made out of the closest pixel of the given image, I saw some code online and came up with the following. What am I doing wrong? I'm new to java, and I am not allowed to use any methods.

```
/**
 * TODO Method to be done. It contains some code that has to be changed
 * 
 * @param enlargeFactorPercentage the border in percentage
 * @param dimAvg                  the radius in pixels to get the average colour
 *                                of each pixel for the border
 * 
 * @return a new image extended with borders
 */
public static BufferedImage addBorders(BufferedImage image, int enlargeFactorPercentage, int dimAvg) {

    // TODO method to be done

    int height = image.getHeight();
    int width = image.getWidth();

    System.out.println("Image height = " + height);
    System.out.println("Image width = " + width);

    // create new image
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height, image.getType());

    // copy image
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            int pixelRGB = image.getRGB(x, y);
            bi.setRGB(x, y, pixelRGB);
        }
    }

    // draw top and bottom borders

    // draw left and right borders

    // draw corners

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            int pixelRGB = image.getRGB(x, y);
            for (enlargeFactorPercentage = 0; enlargeFactorPercentage < 10; enlargeFactorPercentage++){
                bi.setRGB(width, enlargeFactorPercentage, pixelRGB * dimAvg);
                bi.setRGB(enlargeFactorPercentage, height, pixelRGB * dimAvg);
            }
        }
    }

    return bi;
```

Comment: "I am not allowed to use any methods" what do you mean?

Comment: How many pixels **wide**/**thick** should the border be?

Comment: Also "What am I doing wrong?" what makes you think you're doing something wrong? Are you getting errors? Is the result wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not allowed to use any methods.

What does that mean? How can you write code if you can't use methods from the API?

```
int enlargeFactorPercentage
```

What is that for? To me, enlarge means to make bigger. So if you have a factor of 10 and your image is (100, 100), then the new image would be (110, 110), which means the border would be 5 pixels?

Your code is creating the BufferedImage the same size as the original image. So does that mean you make the border 5 pixels and chop off 5 pixels from the original image?

Without proper requirements we can't help.

> @return a new image extended with borders

Since you also have a comment that says "extended", I'm going to assume your requirement is to return the larger image.

So the solution I would use is to:

1. create the BufferedImage at the increased size
2. get the Graphics2D object from the BufferImage
3. fill the entire BufferedImage with the color you want for the border using the `Graphics2D.fillRect(….)` method
4. paint the original image onto the enlarged BufferedImage using the `Graphics2D.drawImage(…)` method.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I am only supposed to use if's, for, while loops and arrays, and I can not use methods like the one you suggested.

Comment: Well, it doesn't really change my answer. You need to start with a larger BufferedImage and then do what the comments in your code say you are going to do. you need 5 loops: 1) Draw the top border 2) draw the bottom border 3) draw the left border 4) draw the right border 5 draw the original image in the center. The only issue is setting the correct x/y values for each of the above loops.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now, what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to stackoverflow!

Not sure what you mean with "not allowed using methods". Without methods you can not even run a program because the "thing" with `public static void main(String[] args)` is a method (the main method) and you need it, because it is the program starting point...

But to answer your question:
You have to load your image. A possibility would be to use ImageIO. Then you create a 2D graphics object and then you can to drawRectangle() to create a border rectangle:

```
BufferedImage bi = //load image
Graphics2D g = bi.getGraphics();
g.drawRectangle(0, 0, bi.getHeight(), bi.getWidth());
```

This short code is just a hint. Try it out and read the documentation from  [Bufferedimage see here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) and from [Graphics2D](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html)

Edit: Please notice that this is not quite correct. With the code above you overdraw the outer pixel-line from the image. If you don't want to cut any pixel of, then you have to scale it up and draw with `bi.getHeight()+2` and `bi.getWidth()+2`. +2 because you need one pixel more at each side of the image.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I am only supposed to use if's, for, while loops and arrays, and I can not use methods like the one you suggested.